# UIImage from CMSampleBufferRef conversion, resulting UIImage not rendering properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, avfoundation

I am working with AV Foundation, i am attempting to save a particular
output CMSampleBufferRef as UIImage in some variable. i am using [manatee works](https://manateeworks.com) sample code and it uses

`kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange` for

`kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey`

```
NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange];

NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];
[captureOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings];
```

but when i save the image, the output is just nil or whatever is the background of `ImageView`. I also tried not to set the output setting and just use whatever is the default but of no use. the image is still not rendered. i also tried to set `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`but then manatee works stops detecting bar code.

I am using the context settings from sample code provided by apple [on developer website](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010192)

```
// Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                             CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                             CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer),
                                             8,
                                             0,
                                             CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
                                             kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
// Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
```

Can anybody help me on what is going wrong here? It should be simple but i don't have much of experience with AVFoundation Framework. Is this is some color space problem as the context is using `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()` ?

I can provide more info if needed. I searched StackOverflow and there were many entries regarding this but none solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you are passing 0 for `bytesPerRow` to `CGBitmapContextCreate`?
Also, you are passing NULL as the buffer instead of the CMSampleBufferRef address.

Creating the bitmap context should look approximately like this when `sampleBuffer` is your `CMSampleBufferRef`:

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress,
                                             CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer),
                                             CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer),
                                             8,
                                             CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer),
                                             colorSpace,
                                             kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
// Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace); 
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);
CGContextRelease(newContext);
```

Comment: This source code is working while video setting is initialized with "kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA". Is there any way to perform UIImage conversion with video setting "kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarVideoRange" ? Actually I am getting camera raw output in YUV NV12 format. Now I want to convert this raw data to UIImage and further process. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I used to do it. The code is written in swift. But it works.
You should notice the orientation parameter at the last line, it depends on the video settings.

```
extension UIImage {
    /**
    Creates a new UIImage from the video frame sample buffer passed.
    @param sampleBuffer the sample buffer to be converted into a UIImage.
    */
    convenience init?(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBufferRef) {
        // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
        let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0)

        // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
        let baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer)

        // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
        let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer)
        // Get the pixel buffer width and height
        let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
        let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)

        // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
        let bitmap = CGBitmapInfo(CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Little.rawValue|CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
            bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmap)
        // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
        let quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)
        // Unlock the pixel buffer
        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0)

        // Create an image object from the Quartz image
        self.init(CGImage: quartzImage, scale: 1, orientation: UIImageOrientation.LeftMirrored)
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't this code doing the same as my code in question? except the last orientation setting?

Answer (score 0):

I use this regularly:

```
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[self imageToBuffer:sampleBuffer]];

    - (NSData *) imageToBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)source {
        CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(source);
        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

        size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
        size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
        size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
        void *src_buff = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:src_buff length:bytesPerRow * height];

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);
        return data;
    }
```